# I know that the word "distinguishing" is not a gerund. what is it then?

Tags: gerunds, parts-of-speech

I know that the word "distinguishing" is not a gerund. what is it then?

> I sometimes have difficulty **distinguishing** Spanish from Portuguese.

source:"https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/distinguish"

Comment: It's a present participle. "Distinguishing Spanish from Portuguese" is a participial clause functioning as catenative complement of "have".

Comment: Some linguists will refer to both as the verb's "-ing form" (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)/[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle#Forms)). But here it's functioning as a verb not a noun (you couldn't use a noun there).

Comment: It's not a verb because it doesn't have a subject pronoun.  You can't say "I distinguishing" - that only works if you have a *be* in there e.g. "I am distinguishing" but that's not the case here.  Valid roles are only participle (=modifier) or gerund (=noun).

Comment: @LawrenceC Non-finite clauses don't usually have overt subjects. Instead the subjects are determined in other ways. Here, the matrix clause has the verb "have" as its head verb, which means that the referent of "I" was having the diffiiculty, and this is enough to tell anyone the understood subject of "distinguishing".

Answer (score 2):

> *I sometimes have difficulty* [*distinguishing Spanish from Portuguese*].

No: it's not a gerund.

This is a catenative construction where "have" is a catenative verb with the bracketed present-participial clause functioning as its catenative complement.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have difficulty distinguishing Spanish from Portuguese.
= I sometimes have difficulty **in** **distinguishing** Spanish from Portuguese.

**In** is a preposition. A preposition can be put before a noun. A gerund (verb + ing) is used as a noun. Here 'distinguishing' is a gerund.

[I have **difficulty** **distinguishing**... = It is **difficult** for me **to distinguish**...]